# Use network_plot to visualise correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, networking, visualization, correlation

I want to visualise the correlation matrix of 60+ attributes. I've tried 'library(corrplot)' and the result shows warning: "too many overlap". Then I tried, which shows a messy plot that the labels are too large and the curves are overlapping.

```
library(corrr)
data %>% correlate() %>% network_plot(min_cor = 0.4)
```

I tried to adjust the label size and curve width following https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memnet/versions/0.1.0/topics/network_plot, it shows error:

> Error in network_plot(correlate(data), min_cor = 0.4, nod_cex = 2,  :
> unused arguments (nod_cex = 2, lab_cex = 1, lab_lwd = 2)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memnet` is a deprecated package that has been removed from CRAN so this is normal you can't use the `network_plot` from this package, but here you are using the `network_plot` function from the `corrr` package which haven't the same arguments : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corrr/versions/0.4.3/topics/network_plot

With 60 variables, I don't think `network_plot` is the best option for visualisation. However, you can try to use `corrplot` as follows :

```
#Create a data frame with random values
df=data.frame(replicate(60,sample(0:60,10,rep=TRUE)))
cor=cor(df)
cor2 <- corrplot::corrMatOrder(cor, order = "FPC", hclust.method = "average")
corrplot::corrplot(cor[cor2,cor2], diag = F, type = "lower",
                       method = "color",  mar = c(1,1,3,1), tl.srt = 60, tl.cex = 0.4)
```

This will produce this graph which will be far more interpretable :
[image]